# Error generating ipa in Swift 5 Xcode 11.2

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

My problem is the following:

I am working with an app A, which makes use of a Framework (Framework B) that I created and that Framework B uses WebP (Swift-WebP) using carthage.

link: https://github.com/ainame/Swift-WebP

In order to use framework B within my app A, I must create the following script in Build Phases:

/ usr / local / bin / carthage copy-frameworks

this is done to be able to use webp that is within Framework B in app A

My problem is that at the time of generating the .ipa, it does not mark error, but when I install my app A from the .ipa on an iphone, the application closes immediately that it tries to open.

The Packaging.log file brings me the following information and tells me some failures that I don't know because they occur:

SDK_HuBOX = Framework B
WebP inside in Framework B

[Packaging.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tkbes.png)

[Packaging.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/98EZT.png)

The application works fine if I run it on the device, the problem is only when the .ipa is generated and installed on a device. even the .ipa is generated, it does not fail but in the registry I find those errors of the images

[Frameworks, Libraries, and Embedded Content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irNOs.png)

[Script in Build Phases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FfKHg.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXNyx.png)

[Link Binary With Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3gygN.png)

I hope someone could help me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I understand what's happing:

Try this:

- Add to "Output files" the follow line: `$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(FRAMEWORKS_FOLDER_PATH)/WebP.framework`
- Add manually(drag and drop) the lib WebP to your "Link Binary With Libraries"

you can see this the same information here but with a lot more details: https://github.com/Carthage/Carthage#if-youre-building-for-ios-tvos-or-watchos

A piece of information I hope to help you in the future, even if your lib(SDK_HuBOX) uses Carthage too, the other libraries will not be included inside your framework automatically, you should include the dependencies on "Link Binary With Libraries" manually as well =)

For example, if your app uses a lib like Moya.framework (my case), you should manually include the other dependencies like Alamofire.framework and Result.framework too because they both are not included on Moya.framework.

I hope this helps.